# Echo something in background but see it even if you rebooted or had a power cut?

Tags: background-process, stdout, sleep

I use Ubutu server 16 .04 and I desire to echo something in the foreground, 2 days ahead, with sleep in the background.

I assume the code I need is similar to the one below (which does both actions in background):

```
(sleep 2d; echo "Surprise!") &
```

---

### The problem

The problem is actually comprised of the problems:

1. I have no idea how to make sleep in the background but its adjacent echo in the foreground.
2. Even if number 1 is possible, If I'll keep my computer opened, this will appear on my (basic shell's) stdout, after 2 days, but what if in between execution and stdout rendering, I rebooted my system, or had a power cut... If I'm not wrong, these will delete the sleep and the echo from memory and I couldn't enjoy the bounty of their combination.

### The question

Is there a way to make an echoed statement appear in my basic shell's stdout (the console I start with after `init`) even if there was a reboot/power cut, in between?

In other words, I just want to make myself a reminder "Do this, do that" after 2 days, regardless of `reboot` or any booting of my system.

Comment: https://www.wikiwand.com/en/At_(Unix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`at`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/at.1p.html) to schedule the job, and [`wall`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/wall.1.html) to broadcast the message to all logged in users:

```
$ echo 'echo some message |wall' | at "now +5 min"
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 6 at Tue Dec  5 00:52:00 2017
```

*[five minutes later]*

```
Broadcast message from i...@...a (somewhere) (Tue Dec  5 00:52:00 2017):

some message
```